# How to put .getScaledInstance

Tags: java, swing

I am making a library system where the user can input images. However, the images don't resize according to the `jlabel`. I don't know how to put `.getScaledInstance` on my image icon. Can you tell me how?

```
format=new ImageIcon (bookImage);
lblImage.setIcon(format);
```

Thank you for your answers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `getScaledInstance(…)` will resize an image to a fixed size that you specify. The size of the label will then be based on the size of the image. If you want the Icon to resize dynamically based on the size of a JLabel then maybe you want the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/)

Comment: *however the images dont resize according to the jlabel.* - what label? Do you have an JLabel with a displayed image and then you try to load another image to make it the same size? *when i click the table the image size did not change* - what "table"? Your question is about a label and I not very clear. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem so we don't have to guess what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use label height and width for the same while you get scaled Instance.

```
Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(),
        Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

Create imageIcon from it.

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(dimg);
```

Comment: I have done doing that in the update buttton but when i click the table the image size did not change.

Comment: what kind of table you are trying to click ? please post some more details to understand your problem.